# Menu in listview header

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for how to show a menu when I click a button in a list view header.
The menu have button, checkbox, spinner and textview.
Then I can't use popup menu. I guess. I've tried to do this using a popup window, but when I open the popup window, if scroll the window don't remain anchor to the button.
What I want is to show the menu over the listview items and anchored to the bottom of the button and when I scroll the list view, the menu remains anchored to button.
The main problem is that popup window go over the current activity and not in.
Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post some code, to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lw1);
        final View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_lw, mDrawerList, false);
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

        ArrayList<String> itemss = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemss.add("Title1");
        itemss.add("Title2");
        itemss.add("Title3");
        itemss.add("Title4");
        itemss.add("Title5");
        itemss.add("Title6");
        itemss.add("Title7");
        itemss.add("Title8");
        itemss.add("Title9");
        itemss.add("Title10");
        itemss.add("Title11");
        itemss.add("Title12");
        itemss.add("Title13");
        itemss.add("Title14");
        itemss.add("Title15");
        itemss.add("Title16");
        itemss.add("Title17");
        itemss.add("Title18");
        itemss.add("Title19");
        itemss.add("Title20");
        itemss.add("Title21");
        itemss.add("Title22");

        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                itemss);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);




        final Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mDrawerList.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.option_menu, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                popupView,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btn1);


            }
        });

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".15"></RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/lw1"
        android:choiceMode="none"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:layout_weight=".85"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

option_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/lnOption"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cb1"
            android:id="@+id/cbAllOff"
            android:checked="false"
            android:buttonTintMode="src_atop"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cb2"
            android:id="@+id/cbAllSpecOff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cbAllOff"
            android:checked="false"
            android:buttonTintMode="src_atop"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

header_lw.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

lw_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".4">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".6"></RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

option_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/lnOption"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cb1"
            android:id="@+id/cbAllOff"
            android:checked="false"
            android:buttonTintMode="src_atop"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cb2"
            android:id="@+id/cbAllSpecOff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cbAllOff"
            android:checked="false"
            android:buttonTintMode="src_atop"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When i click on the button the popup window show anchored to the button. If I scroll the listView and the button in header become not visible, the popup window go over the action bar. There is a way to show the menu option over the list items and anchored to the button in the header?

Thanks!